# How to create a zoomable, pannable, scrollable map with selectable graticles?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, google-maps, d3.js

In a Ruby on Rails application, I need to create a map overlaid with selectable graticlues/ grid squares.

There are many mapping services out there (e.g., Google, OpenStreetMap, etc), in fact the app already uses Google Maps elsewhere.

But now I need to overlay a map with a grid that has selectable graticules.

The grid dimensions are defined (e.g., 1 degree) and should align with lines of lat/ lon (i.e., should scroll, pan and zoom with the map).

The grid is labelled with x-y coordinates (e.g, x-axis is labelled A to Z, whereas y-axis is labelled 1 to 30). Selecting a graticule should return its x-y coordinates and update a form field with this value.

Obviously I could achieve this by carving up an image of the map and creating buttons from each tile. However I would then lose the ability to zoom and pan.

I'd like to minimize the number of libraries the app needs, and where possible use libraries already in use, such as Google Maps and D3.

After much Google searching I've found nothing of relevance. Where would I start creating such a feature? Appreciate any suggestions or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about something like that because I will have to write a function like this in the next months. I was thinking do I simulate this by creating a series of rectangular polygons geo localized they can be selected according to the click event properly stratified than other objects with an appropriate z-index. The polygons may have edges, colors and opacity to configure the look and feel fit. With this assumption does not need any additional javascript library. The normal google maps is more than enough and all the work focuses on the management of an array of polygons, its population according to the grid that you want to accomplish and the management of the individual event on the polygon. One difficulty you will meet if you want to display text. Google maps does not provide tools to give yourself this, why you may need additional libraries such http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/examples/maplabel.html